# Javascript function call from file

Tags: javascript

So...my homework says...

create a function named `calcBMI()` that performs the calculation using the values in the weight and height text boxes and assign the result to the BMI text box.
Convert the value to an Integer number by using the parseInt() function.
Reference the text boxes from within the function by using the documentobject.getElementByID(name), and the value attribute of each text box (in other words, don’t use function arguments AKA pass values to the function).
Add an event listener to to call the calcBMI() function

I have done that here. Keep in mind the javascript file is being reference in the html. Whenever I press the calculate button nothing happens.

```
  function calcBMI() {


    var weight = parseInt(documentobject.getElementByID("weight"));

    var height = parseInt(documentobject.getElementByID("height"));

    var result = (weight * 703) / (height * height);

    var textbox = documentobject.getElementById('Result');

    textbox.value = result;
}


 document.getElementById("submit").
      addEventListener("click", calcBMI(), false);
```

Comment: what is the html? are any errors thrown?

Answer (score 2):

*I see 3 things:*

1. accessing the DOM object rather than its value
2. using `documentobject` rather than `document`
3. invoking a function instead of passing it as a callback.

Here's to resolve the DOM element issue:
`var weight = parseInt(document.getElementByID("weight").value)`
Use the same for the other variables.

It looks like you may be invoking calcBMI() rather than passing it as a callback calcBMI
`.addEventListener("click", calcBMI, false);`

Check out [MDN on event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

It also looks like you were referencing `documentobject` rather than `document`.

`var textbox = documentobject.getElementById('Result');`

Try this:
`var textbox = document.getElementById('Result');`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

When calling `addEventListener()` you need to pass a reference to the callback function. You are calling the function, which is not correct. Try this instead:

`document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", calcBMI, false);`

Comment: Do I need to add anyting to the html file for the function to work? Whenever I click submit everyting just goes back to 0.

Comment: Is the page being reloaded? If so, it's probably because a form is being submitted. You'll have to add JS code to stop that from happening. Without seeing your HTML, it's hard to tell.

Comment: <main>

<article>


<h2>BMI Calculator</h2>

      <form>
         <input type="textbox" id="weight" value="0" />
         <label for="weight">Weight in pounds</label>
         <input type="textbox" id="height" value="0" />
         <label for="height">Height in inches</label>
         <input type="textbox" id="Result" value="0" />
         <label for="textbox">BMI Result <readonly></label>
         <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Calculate BMI" />
  </form>

</article>

</main>

Answer (score 0):

You assign dom elements to weight and height variables. You should get the value of the text field.

```
function calcBMI() {
    var weight = parseInt(document.getElementByID("weight").value);
    var height = parseInt(document.getElementByID("height").value);
    var result = (weight * 703) / (height * height);
    var textbox = document.getElementById('Result');
    textbox.value = result;
}
```